# error Performing erlang migration to another node

Tags: rabbitmq, centos, erlang

I have 2 nodes rabbit2 and rabbit3 everything is working fine until i start cluster
then I did the command
scp -r rabbit2:/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie .
and after successfully transferring the failed nodes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX1Bo.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the cookie file not used because the file permission setting or other cookie file has been used for priority reason.

Do you know how to run rabbitmq in erlang console mode?
If you can, enter the console first, check the problem by command.

[erlang cookie check function](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/auth.html#cookie-0)